# What to do when stripe returns requires_confirmation (php/js)

Tags: stripe-payments

I'm working through the STRIPE payment intents example on [stripe.com/docs/.../upgrade-to-handle-actions](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/payment-intents/upgrade-to-handle-actions) (and [stripe.com/docs/.../accept-a-payment-synchronously](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment-synchronously?platform=web#web-recollect-cvc)) and have got to the part in their generateResponse() code that says "any other status would be unexpected, so error"

```
function generateResponse($intent) {
    if ($intent->status == 'succeeded') {
       // Handle post-payment fulfillment
       echo json_encode(['success' => true]);
    } elseif ($intent->status == 'requires_action') {
       # Tell the client to handle the action
       echo json_encode([
               'requiresAction' => true,
               'clientSecret' => $intent->client_secret
       ]);
    } else {
       // Any other status would be unexpected, so error           <------------------
       echo json_encode(['error' => 'Invalid PaymentIntent status']);
    }
}
```

but I am receiving a "requires_confirmation" using the "insufficient funds" test card "4000008260003178", and I'm not sure what I should be doing in response; My code can be seen and run on [methodfish.com](https://methodfish.com/stripe/stripe_elements_checkout_x#Code).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok - I think the code was getting in a muddle and maybe repeatedly calling itself - so I've re-order the logic so that the authentication is handled fully through the client side (with API calls where necessary). Corrected (?) code/sandbox can be found on [methodfish.com](https://www.methodfish.com/stripe/stripe-elements-checkout-onsession)

Answer (score 0):

If you receive a status of requires_confirmation due to insufficient funds, then that else block would handle that case (since insufficient funds is considered an error). You can improve your error messaging to specifically handle the insufficient funds case if you like, though. I recommend taking a look at [Stripe's error handling docs](https://stripe.com/docs/error-handling?lang=php).

Comment: Not seeing any discussion about "requires_confirmation" or "insufficient funds" on that page - are you sure that page is what you meant?

Comment: Yeah I just meant to link the generic error handling docs. For insufficient funds specifically, that means retrying the payment likely won't succeed. The way to handle this case would be to display an error to the customer indicating they don't have funds, instructing them to provide a different card. You can just add another check in that if-else block to handle this case and return an appropriate error.